# Spark DF to Tableau TDE

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Requirement: Write a DF created by loading data from sql server to a tableau extract(.tde) using spark
 I used this external jar file provided
https://spark-packages.org/package/werneckpaiva/spark-to-tableau
 and started spark shell as below

```
spark-shell --driver-class-path D:\Spark\jdbc\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre7\sqljdbc41.jar --packages werneckpaiva:spark-to-tableau:0.1.0
```

Shell loaded without errors and I have created the DF using below code and DF.Show(10) is also working fine

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc) import TableauDataFrame._
val jdbcSqlConnStr = "jdbc:sqlserver://IP:1433;databaseName=Dbname;user=UserName;password=Password;"
val jdbcDbTable = "dbo.TableName"
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url",jdbcSqlConnStr).option("dbtable",jdbcDbTable).load()
//To check DF
jdbcDF.show(10)
```

Except that, now when I call the command, it thorows below error

```
jdbcDF.write.format("tableau").save("D:\\Spark\\mydata.tde")
error: value TableauDataFrame is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
```

From few reading, I tried to import the classs implicitly as below which also throws error

```
import TableauDataFrame._
<console>:23: error: not found: value TableauDataFrame
       import TableauDataFrame._
```

Could someOne help me what I am missing

Comment: I dont think that is possible as of now. I just cross checked all the datasources available in Spark 2.2.0, and only found csv, jdbc, json, orc, parquet, text and v2. Also, did not find any library thats already created on github. What you can do is dump, it in some intermediate format like CSV or Parquet and load the same again from tableau. Let us know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by placing all required jars(the ones including in the package werneckpaiva:spark-to-tableau:0.1.0) in spark bin folder and calling the jars as below

```
spark-shell --driver-class-path sqljdbc41.jar;spark-to-tableau-0.1.0.jar
```

Then I am able to import everything as below

```
import tableau.TableauDataFrame._
import tableau.TableauDataFrameImplicity
```